# Unallocated space Disk 0 to Disk 1

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

Can someone point me to the right direction how to allocate the unused space into Disk 1? I cannot move un-allocated data from Disk 0 to Disk 1 (see attached).

[image: storage issue]

Comment: You cannot literally move unused space between *physical* disks. It's like moving an empty room from your house to a house two streets away.

Comment: You cannot extend the space from disk 0 to your disk 1 by design. Unless you want to reinstall the whole Windows, you can format delete all volume in disk 1 and disk 0, then create storage space to extend the drive capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Each row in the diagram represents a physical device. Unused space cannot be attached to another physical drive, because as @Kamil mentioned already, it is *physically part of your drive* – you cannot take out some flash chips or HDD platters and put them elsewhere.

Unused space *could* be attached to the logical drive (volume) `C:`, using either Windows' "Dynamic disks" technology (note: I seem to remember that this feature is no longer actively supported by Microsoft), or some third-party volume management tools.

But still I **wouldn't** suggest doing so if the disks are of completely different types (guessing purely from size, it seems like you want to join a HDD and an SSD). That would give you all the space but none of the performance: you would have absolutely no control over which files (or filesystem metadata) go into the 'fast' disk, and very possibly *all* operations would be as slow as the slowest disk.

If they're indeed an SSD & an HDD, then after moving the entire C: volume to the HDD it would become possible to use the SSD **as a cache**, similar to the way hybrid "SSHDs" work. SSD-based caching is implemented by Intel's iRST driver as well as other third-party software. This would be more predictable, as *frequently used* blocks would be copied to the fast drive, and more reliable because the HDD would still contain the original data in any case. (You wouldn't get the combined space though; you'd get *only* space from the HDD – but that's still quite a lot.)

On the other hand, if they're both disks of the same type, just move the entire C: volume to disk 0 and ignore disk 1 completely.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanations. C drive is SDD and drive D is HDD. Can you please guide me how to implement your second approach (viz. to use SSD as cache)? If there are third party app can do this please advise.       Cheers

Comment: @shz.q8: If your computer has an Intel SATA controller, look up "Intel Smart Response Technology".

Comment: thanks mate; my computer has one installed; I will look into it.